# Javascript Animation Baseball Runners

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas, svg

Thank you in advance for you help. I am hoping someone could provide some solid examples of some Javascript or jQuery animation for running around a baseball diamond rather than starting from scratch.
[image]

So far I've found at least 1 think that gets me close however needs much control introduced. I'm looking for tracking live progress so this would be conditional based on the batters progress around the bases. So if the batter hit a double, the animation would go to 2nd base and stop. Eventually I need to add functionality to interact with the circle but that'll be another story.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
var context;
var x=100;
var y=200;
var dx=3;
var dy=3;

function init()
{
  context= myCanvas.getContext('2d');
  setInterval(draw,10);
}

function draw()
{
 context.clearRect(0,0, 300,300);
 context.beginPath();
 context.fillStyle="#0000ff";
 // Draws a circle of radius 20 at the coordinates 100,100 on the canvas
 context.arc(x,y,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
 context.closePath();
 context.fill();
 // Boundary Logic
 if( x<0 || x>300) dx=-dx; 
 if( y<0 || y>300) dy=-dy; 
 x+=dx; 
 y+=dy;
 }

</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init();">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300" > </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm wondering how your code might be look like

Comment: Sounds like a job for SVG expert

Comment: What is _"Box movement"_ ? _"rather than starting from scratch. "_ ?

Comment: Maybe as a starting point: http://jsfiddle.net/4LzK4/

Comment: Examples? That's what google is for. SO isn't an idea factory. When you have example code that comes close but isn't working right...then you ask questions

Comment: thanks for your helpful advice charlietfl! Troll much?

Comment: I cannot find any examples after many attempts, hence why I am asking. I'm sure there is someone working with something or knows where I can find something at least partly that i can use.

Comment: Just an FYI to be accurate you would want the dots running around the inside diamond (basepath/infield) not the outfield this also might make the animation a bit easier since they are straight lines

Answer (score 1):

Lots of negative votes and I can see why, however its actually quite straightforward if you use svg and a library, eg Snap.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/910g7cbL/3/) click to move between bases

Here's a run down of the process....

Firstly load an svg, just plucked one from the internet, and load it..

```
Snap.load( "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Baseball_diamond_clean.svg", onSVGLoaded )
```

We need to create a route, simply log a mouse click to get its x,y which you can use to create a path...

```
s.click( setRoute );

function setRoute(ev, x,y) {
  console.log('xy', ev, x, y); // a click will log coordinates so you can build path route
  movePlayer(currentPath++);
  if( currentPath > 3) currentPath = 0;
}
```

Once you've clicked on the points you want to have as the path, add them into the array....

```
// build our 'virtual path' and player to animate when clicked

function onSVGLoaded( frag ) {
  s.append( frag );
  s.click( setRoute )
  paths = [
    "M335,430L448,324",  // these were logged from mouse click
    "M453,325L337,210",
    "M330,210L215,324",
    "M215,325L330,436"
  ];

  player = s.circle(335,430,10).attr({ fill: 'red' })
  for( var c=0; c<paths.length; c++) {
    pathList[c] = s.path(paths[c]).attr({ stroke: 'none' });
  }
}
```

Finally, we can animate the movement...

```
function movePlayer( currentPath ) {
  Snap.animate(0, pathList[currentPath].getTotalLength(), function( val ) {
    var pt = pathList[currentPath].getPointAtLength( val );
player.attr({ cx: pt.x, cy: pt.y })
  }, 2000)
}
```

edit: Heh, just seen how old this is, not sure why it popped up now!

Answer (score 0):

**Using Html5 Canvas**

You can use `linear interpolation` to navigate your lines and you can use `De Casteljau's algorithm` to navigate around your Bezier Curve.

**Using SVG**

Svg Paths have built-in methods that give you the total length of the path: `getTotalLength` and also the X,Y at a specified length along the path: `getPointAtLength`. You can use these methods to navigate your lines and curves.